# How to clear the bottom of a float if text is below it

Tags: html, css

I am making a web that's like a facebook where there is a image on the left and text on the right but if the text reach the bottom of the image it goes to the bottom of image. Its hard to explain so I will attached a screenshot

```css
.comment {
  width: 100%;
}

.comment img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.comment img:after {
  content: "";
}

strong {
  color: #365899;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="View_post-1" class="row">
  <div>
    <div class="comment">
      <img src="../Image/Mark Anthony Fernandez.jpg">
      <small>
         <strong style="">Mark Anthony Fernandez</strong>
      </small>
      <br />
      <div>
        <span style="font-size:small;position:relative;word-wrap:break-word;">commentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcomment</span>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to define `margin-left` for your text side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well you don't want the text to wrap around the image to the left.
You can use flexbox to achieve that and it will give you a responsive solution.
I have created a codepen for your case: https://codepen.io/frexos/pen/yPjqYm

```
<div id="View_post-1" class="row">
  <div>
    <div class="comment">
      <img src="../Image/Mark Anthony Fernandez.jpg">
      <div class="text">
          <small>
              <strong style="">Mark Anthony Fernandez</strong>
          </small>
          <br />
          <div>
              <span style="font-size:small;position:relative;word-wrap:break-word;">commentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcomment</span>
          </div>
      </div>  
  <br>
</div>
```

```
.comment {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
}

.comment img {
display: block;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
float: left;
}

.comment img:after {
content: "";
}

strong {
color: #365899;
font-weight: bold;
}

.text {
min-width: 10%;
word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks you are using bootstrap to set your layout, you can use `media object` for this, check updated snippet below... for detail reference [click here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media)

```css
.comment{
width:100%;
}
.comment img{
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.comment img:after{
    content:"";
}
strong{
    color:#365899;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="View_post-1" class="row">
 <div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
     <img class="media-object" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/cccccc/ff0000.png&text=Sample-Text">   
  </div>
  <div class="media-body"><small>
    <strong style="">Mark Anthony Fernandez</strong>
   </small>
   <br />
   <div>
   <span style="font-size:small;position:relative;word-wrap:break-word;">commentcommentcommentcom mentcommentcommentcommentcommen tcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentc ommentcommentcommentcom mentcommentco mmentcommentcomme ntcommentcommentcommentcomme ntcomm entcommentcommentcomme ntcommentcommentcommentcommentcommen tcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentc ommentcommentcomm entcomment</span>
   </div>
   <br>
  </div>
</div> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the width of the image you can just add a padding left to your div containing the text.

```
.comment > div{ padding-left: 50px;}
```

```css
.comment {
  width: 100%;
}

.comment img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.comment img:after {
  content: "";
}

strong {
  color: #365899;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.comment > div{ padding-left: 50px;}
```

```html
<div id="View_post-1" class="row">
  <div>
    <div class="comment">
      <img src="../Image/Mark Anthony Fernandez.jpg">
      <div>
      <small>
          <strong style="">Mark Anthony Fernandez</strong>
      </small>
      <br />
      <div>
        <span style="font-size:small;position:relative;word-wrap:break-word;">commentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcomment</span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.comment div{
    display: flex;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```css
.comment {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .comment .image {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
  }
  .comment img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  .content {
    float: left;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 80px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 80px);
    width: -ms-calc(100% - 80px);
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
  }

  .comment img:after {
    content: "";
  }

  strong {
    color: #365899;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div id="View_post-1" class="">
  <div>
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="../Image/Mark Anthony Fernandez.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <small>
          <strong style="">Mark Anthony Fernandez</strong>
        </small>
        <br />
        <div>
          <span style="font-size:small;position:relative;word-wrap:break-word;">commentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcommentcomment</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```